# Why isn't the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}$ equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

According to Principles of Mathematical Analysis page 156,
“Sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}\ \ \ (0\leq x\leq 1,n=1,2,3\cdots)$ is not equicontinuous.” I want to know the proof of above statement!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=1$ and that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n\left(0\right)=0$. Therefore, given $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, you will not be able to find a $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):-\delta<x<\delta\Longrightarrow\bigl|f_n(x)-f_n(0)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Sorry about wrong question $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: What difference does it make? Just replace “$x\in\mathbb{R}$” with “$x\in[0,1]$”.